# How to pass my array of objects into a graph with Chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, graph, chart.js

Hello I am trying to present my array of objects in a graph with Chart.js here is the code

```
let timers = {neutral: 0, happy: 0, sad: 0, angry: 0, surprised: 0, disgust: 0};
var detection = new Chart(c, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Neutral", "Happy", "Sad", "Angry", "Surprised", "Disgust"],
        datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', // neutral
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // happy
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', // sad
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', // angry
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)', // surprised
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'   // disgust
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'                        
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: timers,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        indexAxis: 'x',
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
                labels: {
                    font: {
                        size: 50
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Emotion timers"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that the graph does not take as labels the one that I am giving to it but instead it takes as labels the names from the object array and due to that I cannot resize the x labels to be bigger. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the chart js documentation, when you give a map (key,value) to data field like `timers` in your case, chart js automatically takes keys as labels and values as data points to be plotted.

So, if you want to give your own labels in spite of this, you can add following snippet to your existing code.

```
var keys = Object.keys(timers);
var values = keys.map(function(v) { return timers[v]; });
```

and pass `values` instead of `timers`.

Full code -

```
let timers = {neutral: 0, happy: 0, sad: 0, angry: 0, surprised: 0, disgust: 0};
var keys = Object.keys(timers);
var values = keys.map(function(v) { return timers[v]; });

var detection = new Chart(c, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Neutral", "Happy", "Sad", "Angry", "Surprised", "Disgust"],
        datasets: [{
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', // neutral
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // happy
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', // sad
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', // angry
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)', // surprised
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'   // disgust
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'                        
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: values,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        indexAxis: 'x',
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false,
                labels: {
                    font: {
                        size: 50
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Emotion timers"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Update:
As you want to update charts as timers are getting updated in setInterval, you have to put chart creation code also in setInterval function.
For example, you can refer to the following full html file

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-Wt1bJGtlnMtGP0dqNFH1xlkLBNpEodaiQ8ZN5JLA5wpc1sUlk/O5uuOMNgvzddzkpvZ9GLyYNa8w2s7rqiTk5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</script>
<script>
    var i = 0;
    
    setInterval(updateChart,3000);
    function updateChart(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myChart");
        let chartStatus = Chart.getChart("myChart"); // <canvas> id
        if (chartStatus != undefined) {
          chartStatus.destroy();
        }
        i = i+1;
        let timers;
        if(i%2==0){
            timers = {neutral: 20, happy: 0, sad: 0, angry: 0, surprised: 0, disgust: 0};
        }
        else{
            timers = {neutral: 0, happy: 20, sad: 0, angry: 0, surprised: 0, disgust: 0};
        }
        var keys = Object.keys(timers);
        var values = keys.map(function(v) { return timers[v]; });
        var detection = new Chart(c, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Neutral", "Happy", "Sad", "Angry", "Surprised", "Disgust"],
                datasets: [{
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', // neutral
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // happy
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', // sad
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', // angry
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)', // surprised
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'   // disgust
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'                        
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    data: keys.map(function(v) { return timers[v]; }),
                }]
            },
            options: {
                indexAxis: 'x',
                responsive: true,
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false,
                        labels: {
                            font: {
                                size: 50
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: "Emotion timers"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
</script>
</head>
<button onclick="updateChart()">Update Chart</button>
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

You can run this html code for better understanding.

Comment: I tried your code and the issue I have is that the objects from the timers get updated inside a setInterval loop so I suppose that because we give the values from the beggining it does not take the new ones

Comment: So, instead of keeping values variable, you can directly write keys.map(function(v) { return timers[v]; }) in place of timers in data parameter, and if you want the chart also to be updated once timers is updated, then you have to copy the whole code in setInterval function because chart cannot be updated automatically even if timers get updated

Comment: Sorry for the late response I will give it a try and see if it will work. Thanks for the advices I just started learning javascript!

Comment: I got one more question when you say the whole code do you mean the one that creates the chart or only the timers, keys, values part?

Comment: You have to put the chart creation code also in the setInterval function along with timers keys and values because chart cannot get updated automatically even if values get. Also, make sure you use 
let chartStatus = Chart.getChart("myChart"); // <canvas> id
if (chartStatus != undefined) {
  chartStatus.destroy();
}
this code before var detection = new Chart statement as the same canvas cannot be updated.

Comment: I have updated the answer by adding the new code. You can refer to that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to let the labels array out of the chart like so:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const timers = {
  neutral: 10,
  happy: 0,
  sad: 0,
  angry: 0,
  surprised: 0,
  disgust: 20
};


const detection = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', // neutral
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', // happy
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', // sad
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', // angry
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)', // surprised
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)' // disgust
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 2,
      data: timers,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'x',
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
        labels: {
          font: {
            size: 50
          }
        }
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Emotion timers"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```